# heliohost and django hosting and deployment from bitbucket

Tags: django, heroku, hosting

I'm new to Django and Heliohost and Heroku.

I don't see any guides online to setup and deploy a Django project from bitbucket for Heliohost. Can you guys point me in the right direction?

And I was wondering is hosting a Django project on Heroku free for small projects?
Should I switch from Heliohost to Heroku?

Thanks everybody. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've hosted multiple small (free-heroku) projects with Heroku and Django - They work very well together. Especially if you don't have a lot of server experience.

Heroku has a straightforward django guide, and using git with your projects to push local changes into heroku is fast/easy.

Heroku has lots of plugins (many for free) that can help out even the smallest django application running on the free level. Memcache is a must, to keep your small apps running as quickly as possible.

All in all Heroku is a great way to host a Django Powered application, it's instantly scale-able when your application is ready to grow, but works well enough in the free capacity in order to let it grow !

Comment: Awesome. what about the database we use? will they charge us on that?
I'm thinking about using a mysql database with django.

Also do you know any method of deployment from bitbucket?

Comment: no you can use the free shared database. Don't be confused with heroku pricing, you can launch an app + database for free on small scale. You have to use PostgreSQL as your database on heroku (but development you can use mysql/sqlite). Not super familiar with bitbucket, deploying to where with bit?